# Constant DB_PASSWORD Wordpress / Opencart

Tags: php, wordpress, opencart

I am attempting to display the latest 3 posts from my blog, On my Opencart site.

The WP blog is at a subdomain blog.domain.com

I am adding this to footer.tpl in OC

```
<?php
require('/var/www/vhosts/blog.domain.com/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

But when i do this i get this error...

Notice: Constant DB_PASSWORD already defined in /var/www/vhosts/blog.domain.com/wp-config.php on line 29
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user '<>'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /var/www/vhosts/blog.domain.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1036

From what i have been reading this is being caused by having 2 DB_PASSWORD defined, assuming that these would be 1 for WP and 1 for OC.

Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: Yes. Either change the constant name in one app or the other, and find/replace all instances, or make use of WP's RSS feed to pull in your posts instead of hacking two apps into one.

Comment: Hey Thanks for pushing to me figure out another way to do this with the RSS feed worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone that is looking for the answer to this later as @sammitch suggested using the RSS feed is a great way to do this here is a code snippet below.

```
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('<<URL TO RSS FEED>>');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
    'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );
    array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 3;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    echo '<li><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.'</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

Probably worth mentioning that i only needed title and link from the array there is a lot of other variables that you can pull out.

Comment: Glad to see that some good came of my snippy, bad-mood remarks yesterday. :D

Comment: I just needed to be pushed to think outside the box i appreciate it even it was a little snippy :) Cheers!